# This system cache are so large?

Tags: deja-dup

I just run a disk analyer for my ubuntu 12.04. I found there is a huge folder under this directory ~/.cache/deja-dup. All the files inside name like duplicity-full.20121019T115047Z.manifest.part / duplicity-full-signatures.20121019T115047Z.sigtar.part

But it contain more than 5G file there. Anyone have any idea what is this file regarding??

Can I delete them as they are eating up my disk storage.

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Firstly, this is not the system cache.  The system cache is a cache that resides in memory and occupies physical memory that is not otherwise used by applications.

This is a .cache folder inside your home directory, so not system-wide at all.  You can, if you need the space, safely delete it (make sure the application that uses it isn't running at the time).  Only a misbehaving program would die if you delete stuff it's put in ~/.cache.

To answer your question though, deja-dup is a backup tool provided by Ubuntu.  The cache probably helps it keep track of all the files in your backup sets.  It probably saves a fair bit of time re-generating this information each time the backup process starts.  Every file in your backup sets, it appears, has signatures stored in a cache.

5G does sound like a lot, though.  If you don't use deja-dup, or you don't care about it losing its cache and being a lot more slow next time it starts, you could delete it.

Comment: Thank you for your information and correcting my knowledge. Thanks a lot!!! I have a clear picture now!!

Comment: for confirmation: https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+question/184246

Comment: I removed the 32 GiB folder (two 16 GiB folders actually, don't know why) in `~/.cache/deja-dup/` and ran the backup, which took 2 hours (normally 10 minutes) and created 10 GiB again in the same folder.